# Get the text of listview Android

Tags: android

I have listview that populated from database.
When I click a row in that listview, it will pass data to another activity with the content of activity depend on the passing data.

This is my code:

```
private final ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

private final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ContentPick.this, Content.class);
        String text = results.get(position);
        i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(text));
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
```

The activity contain listview also have edittext that have filtering (when I type some text in the edittext it will filter the listview according to the text). The problem is, if I'm click a row in listview after I filtered it, the activity that showing is same result as if I'm not filter the listview.

Example:
When the edittext is empty, the first row of the listview is `Cell structure` . When I click the `Cell structure` it will show information about Cell structure.
I click Back, and I type `Blood` in EditText, it will filter the listview, and the first row of the listview is `Blood Cell`.  When I click the row `Blood Cell`, it still show information about Cell Structure.

What I'm trying to do is with this code:

```
String text = results.get(position);
```

But I think it's the cause of the problem.
Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I finally solve the problem.
I make a method displayResult and I set the adapter like this

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
```

In the method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, I change variable text to this

```
String text = dataAdapter.getItem(position);
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

change position in your code.like below

```
final int position
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to actual notify your dataset position. It might help you to solve problem.